# alternative for Javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have been using Java for years I really like the language except javadoc.
The document generated by javadoc makes me feel I am browsing web in 1990s. To make some beauty doc you have to insert obscure html tags which make your comments almost unreadable before generating html file.

I am seeking some alternative for javadoc, reStructuredText is my first choice but there is no doclet for it. Another choice is markdown, but it mainly aims to html so I treat it as my last resort if I can't figure out any other way.

I am also considering split comment from java file, but it bothers developers who browse code in IDE.

Any good ideas?

Comment: Take a look at [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) I used it for a couple project and find it very powerful and quite good looking for a documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not need to use an alternative to Javadoc.
If you are using Java 7, the new version of Javadoc has been redesigned.

Here's an example of the output: [Java 7 Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Comment: I have to agree that javadoc 6 is boring, but javadoc 7 is nice. javadoc 8 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) is even better.

Comment: thanks, the redesign makes it much better